# I want to call an AWS Rest API from a classic ASP application running in IIS on Windows Server 2008 SP2

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, asp-classic, windows-server-2008

When I run the following code, I get an error.

```
Dim objXMLHTTP
set objXMLHTTP = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
objXMLHTTP.Open "GET", "https://hogehoge/student/123456", false 
objXMLHTTP.setOption 2, 13056
objXMLHTTP.Send()
```

#### Error Contents

> Error code : 80072F8F
> Error contents : A security error has occurred.

*It's being shown by Japanese and is translated.*

#### Windows Event Viewer

> System log is represented by the following content has been output.
> ”The SSL server handshake is complete.”

#### Environment

> Windows Server 2008 SP2
>
> Update program "KB4019276" applied

The following registry has been registered

> DisabledByDefault : 0
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Client
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Server
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Server

Comment: When you search for that error, a lot of pages come up about having the date/time incorrect on the server.  Have you check that?    Have you confirmed what version of TLS the API expects?

Comment: thank you for your comment.
The time is set correctly.
TLS1.1 or higher is allowed.

Comment: Did you find a fix for this? - I'm experiencing a very similar problem